# Google Container Engine (GKE) Kubernetes Custom DNS Entries

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a Kubernetes Cluster on Google Container Engine with the default SkyDNS implementation enabled.

How can I add custom DNS Entries in Google Container Engine?  Is there any way to:

1. Add custom DNS Entries to SkyDNS that will persist if the SkyDNS container is restarted?
2. Change the default DNS Settings on my nodes to a custom DNS Server, which in-turn will forward to SkyDNS?
3. Change the Forward DNS of SkyDNS to my custom DNS Server?

Edit: If trying to resolve a Google Compute Engine VM from inside a container, the default DNS Server that Google Container Engine uses will resolve VM Names in the formats:

```
<vm-name>.c.<project-name>.internal
<vm-name>.<project-id>.google.internal
```

Comment: You should look at my answer on a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43468742/1425670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is not any API to directly manipulate DNS within the cluster.  It's something we want to do but have not tackled yet.

Can you explain what you're hoping to achieve?

Edit: if you want to run Consul, nothing is stopping you.  Our DNS server is just one implementation.

Comment: I was hoping to set up an internal DNS server inside my Compute Engine project so that my Kubernetes containers can resolve other GCE VMs in my project on the internal network.

Comment: The default DNS server should be able to resolve VM names by default.  Is it not working?

Comment: Good to know, the default DNS server does resolve VM names properly.  Is there any way to reliably resolve DNS for one of the GKE Nodes for GCE VM -> GKE NodePort communication without naming a specific GKE VM?  Like a round robin DNS for the Instance Group?

Comment: As far as I know there is not a DNS pool assigned to an instance group.